# Can one find a surjection $f:D\to{\bf C}$ such that $f$ is not a rational function?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

By considering a Mobius transformation, one can find a bijection between the open unit disc $D$ and the upper half plane $H$ and thus further give a surjection from $D$ to the whole complex plane ${\bf C}$. Can one find a surjection $f:D\to{\bf C}$ such that $f$ is *not* a rational function?

Comment: These sets have the same cardinality, so the answer is certainly yes. What are you requiring of $f$? Continuity?

Comment: Use $\exp$ as the surjection $H \to \mathbb{C}$ instead of a power?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Exp doesn't take the value 0...That's why I used $\sin(z)$ in my answer :)

Comment: @Mr.Chip: I should have added that $f$ is supposed to be holomorphic as well. But it is too late to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $\sin(z) : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is surjective, the function 
$$f(z)= \sin(g(z))$$
where $g: D\to{\bf C}$ is your favorite (rational) surjection satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $re^{it} \to \tan (\pi r/2)e^{it}.$